# Expect log processing to be stored all in one place in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

A clear and concise description of what the problem is. Ex. I'm always frustrated when [...]
In the current container environment, part of the discovery logs are stored in the specified location of the configuration file, and part of them can be obtained through docker logs. It is hoped that it can be handled uniformly in the future.
For example, the current environment is different by checking the logs at the specified location and the docker logs logs. as follows:

```
root@a9076e5ed80b:/# tail -f /var/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-27  -n 100
2023-10-27T03:27:57.205045557Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T03:29:57.210976306Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T03:35:57.236692887Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T04:05:57.434011202Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T04:44:57.639819620Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T05:59:58.029251750Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T08:12:58.746120304Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
2023-10-27T08:14:58.752662242Z  INFO coordinator::resource_manager: resource is executing by 5
.....
docker logs containerid
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  PrimitiveArray expected data type Float64 got Null
Location: /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/arrow-array-42.0.0/src/array/primitive_array.rs:567

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 8 frames hidden ⋮                               
   9: <arrow_array::array::primitive_array::PrimitiveArray<T> as core::convert::From<arrow_data::data::ArrayData>>::from::h7c7578441671feec
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  10: <core::iter::adapters::GenericShunt<I,R> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::h487b21e85463b690
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: protocol_parser::lines_convert::MutableBatch::to_arrow_with_schema_padding::h09ce896ec8327098
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: <coordinator::service::CoordService as coordinator::Coordinator>::write_lines::{{closure}}::h47db9e7423392bfe
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::http::http_service::coord_write_points_with_span_recorder::{{closure}}::ha044055795728215
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: <warp::filter::and_then::State<T,F> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h2f06bd768950cd24
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: <warp::filter::or::EitherFuture<T,U> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::he195a4d5f2ff9f07
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: <warp::filter::service::FilteredFuture<F> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::hab57f18d8bd984b9
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  17: <hyper::server::conn::ProtoServer<T,B,S,E> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h1aea579c8db100f0
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  18: <hyper::server::server::new_svc::NewSvcTask<I,N,S,E,W> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h42f1bbdaec2460f3
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  19: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::hcb5fabdf73571d64
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  20: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::Context::run_task::hea04f7f809d3c82d
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  21: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::run::h9e5095a87649f363
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  22: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::heaa514002d253556
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  23: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hc7e3e42753363e8c
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  24: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h809ac74f53a1cf92
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  25: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::hee65a93bb9e457d5
      at /rustc/84dd17b56a931a631a23dfd5ef2018fd3ef49108/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1973
  26: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::h9c85ee39510778f9
      at /rustc/84dd17b56a931a631a23dfd5ef2018fd3ef49108/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1973
  27: std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h7337197a7019439e
      at /rustc/84dd17b56a931a631a23dfd5ef2018fd3ef49108/library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108
  28: __clone<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```